ARM TEMPLATE: Is it possible to change subnets of private endpoint?
I got an error when I tried to change subnets of private endpoint using ARM template.
Error message is like below.
Cannot change the subnet in which the network interface for private endpoint.

I was under the impression that if I changed the value of subnets in the ARM template and deployed it, it would change the subnets of the existing private endpoints.
From the error message it doesn't seem to do that. Does anybody know any solution?
Any answer would be helped. Thank you.
PS.
Here is a part of tried code.
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
    "apiVersion": "2024-01-01",
    "name": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName]",
    "location": "eastus2",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].subscription, variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
            {
                "name": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName]",
                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName), concat('/privateLinkServiceConnections/', variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName))]",
                "properties": {
                    "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].subscription, variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]",
                    "groupIds": [
                        "file"
                    ],
                    "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
                        "status": "Approved",
                        "description": "Auto-Approved",
                        "actionsRequired": "None"
                    }
                }
             }
        ],
        "manualPrivateLinkServiceConnections": [],
        "customNetworkInterfaceName": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].networkInterfaceName]",
        "subnet": {
            "id": "[concat(variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName, '/subnets/', variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].subnets)]"
        },
        "ipConfigurations": [],
         "customDnsConfigs": []
    }
},      

I just want to change "subnet" of private endpoint and I only changed variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].subnets in variable section.

Can you share the code you tried @CuteeeRabbit

@VinayB Thank you for the comment. I added code that I tried to deploy. Please check it.


ARM TEMPLATE: Is it possible to change subnets of private endpoint?

The direct answer for this in the first place was NO. we can't achieve this using ARM template as this subnet is attached to private endpoint, we need to destroy dependances manually using the CLI commands or azure portal first.

Initially I created on as mentioned in the above. Now when i tried to achieve this requirement of changing the subnet I faced to blocker mentioned below.

Here I used CLI commands to do this task
az network private-endpoint delete --name vksbPrivateEndpoint --resource-group vinay-rg

&
az network vnet subnet delete --name initialSubnet --vnet-name myVNet --resource-group vinay-rg

Once the private end point and subnet got deleted then update the JSON with relevant subnet info as mentioned in the requirement
ARM template:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "myVNet",
      "location": "eastus2",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "10.0.0.0/16"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "newSubnet",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "10.0.2.0/24"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
      "name": "vbskstorageaccount",
      "location": "eastus2",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {
        "accessTier": "Hot"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
      "apiVersion": "2024-01-01",
      "name": "vksbPrivateEndpoint",
      "location": "eastus2",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'myVNet')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'vbskstorageaccount')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "subnet": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'myVNet', 'newSubnet')]"
        },
        "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
          {
            "name": "vksbPrivateLinkConnection",
            "properties": {
              "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'vbskstorageaccount')]",
              "groupIds": [
                "file"
              ],
              "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
                "status": "Approved",
                "description": "Auto-Approved",
                "actionsRequired": "None"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/private-endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet/subnet?view=azure-cli-latest
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet/subnet?view=azure-cli-latest
Error: Changing Subnet and Private Endpoint using ARM Template 
